# How do I write every line of a file which contains a given word and has at least a given number of characters in a line using AWK?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Let's say I have two text files (sample1.txt, sample2.txt) and a shell script file(myscript.sh) which contains the AWK.
**sample1.txt:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum
ipsum
```

**sample2.txt**

```
 Nunc ipsum ultricies aliquet nisl eu hendrerit.
 Nunc ipsum
```

If I type in the console: ./myscript ipsum 5 sample1.txt sample2.txt I want to see:
`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet` 
`Lorem ipsum`
`Nunc ipsum ultricies aliquet nisl eu hendrerit.`
`Nunc ipsum`

**myscript.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
echo Usage: word number files
exit 1
fi

re2='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ $2 =~ $re2 ]] ; then
echo "$2 is not a number"
exit 1
fi

word=$1
lines=$2
shift
shift

for i
do
if [ ! -f $i ]; then
echo "$i is not a file!"
exit 1
fi

awk -var=$lines 'BEGIN{};
(length($0)>var){'/$word'/}
END{}
' $*
done
```

This doesn't have any output unfortunately!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do

```
lines=5; word=ipsum;
```

values set

```
awk -v lines="$lines" -v word="$word" 'length($0)>lines && $0~word' files
```

for the given files, will produce

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum
 Nunc ipsum ultricies aliquet nisl eu hendrerit.
 Nunc ipsum
```

Note that in your script the variable defined is `ar`, not `var`.  You have empty `BEGIN`, `END` blocks.  Also `bash` cannot substitute variable values under single quotes (your $word).  Even so matching `/variable/` is not going to work since `variable` treated to as literal.  Right way to match is with `~` operator as in my script.

Based on the comment below, if you're looking for an exact word match, perhaps easier to do equality check (alternative is using word boundaries)

```
$ ... 'length($0)>var{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i==word) {print; next}}' file
```

now `ipsumthingswrong` will not match.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are trying to do something like this:

```
$ awk -v search="ipsum" 'length($0) != length(search) && $0 ~ search{print}' file1 file2
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum
Nunc ipsum ultricies aliquet nisl eu hendrerit.
Nunc ipsum
```